# How to resolve my SOAP issues?

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a windows app to test connecting to a 3rd party web service.

I've created a service reference using the wsdl that was provided.

The way the web service will work is a 4 step process.

1. Method call to get session ID.
2. Method call to pass arguments
3. Method call to execute arguments.
4. Method call to get results.

Now here is the strange part:
I can make the first call no issue.

Calls 2 and 3 do not work from my . net appliaction.

I get the error:
Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'setArguments'. End element 'Body' from namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' expected. Found element 'ns:setArgumentsResponse'

I am at a total loss with this.

What I've done.

1. I am capturing my post in Fiddler.

   - When I examine the body everything looks correct.
   - If I take the same response that I captured and post it in Fiddler it works.
2. I've tried the this in Python at it works.

Is there some obscure setting that I could possibly be missing in my application?

My findings in step 1 should prove that I am creating a valid request.  Could . NET possibly be choking on the response?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

FYI:
binding="customBinding"
I've also tried basicBinding and got the same results.

EDIT:
I just wrapped a try/catch around each method and when I call method 4 I get a result.  So the error must be on the response.  Right?

Comment: With one you're doing a get so there is less chance of a serialization problem occurring than when you're sending to them. When you added the service reference, did you point it at the host address you're calling? How complex is the data you're passing to them?

Comment: Method2(string, string[])  See my edit...

Answer (score 0):

Issues appears to be that I am consuming a Java web service.

I originally added it as a Service Reference which is causing my serialization errors on the response.

I removed this reference and re-added a Web Reference and it appears to be working without the serialization error.